# Insert many into sql table on duplicate update

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am new to mysql, I am trying to insert many into a table and if there is a duplicate name just ignore it and move on. I am currently working in nodejs. Here is a sample of my code

```
 let sql = `INSERT INTO integrations
            (name)
           VALUES ? 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
           name=VALUES(name)`;
this.connection.query(sql, [this.createValues()], function (err :any, result: any) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('modified ' + result.affectedRows + "records(s)");
});
```

createValues() returns an array like

```
["bob", "mike", "anna", "theo", "karen"]
```

The issue is the values are always inserted again, I end up with multiple of the same name value in the table.
What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Do you have a unique index or pk on the name field?

Comment: Yes, I used TypeOrm to create the table here is the entity for this export class Integrations {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;
}

Comment: Then you cannot have duplicates in your column.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, `name` has to be declared as `unique` (or as the primary key).  In the databases, you can do this by creating a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_integrations_name on integrations(name);
```

This only has to be done once, typically when the table is created.